# File operations in Android service

Tags: android, file, service

Android services might get killed by the operating system at any possible time. There are no guaranteed lifecycle calls like `onDestroy()` you can rely on. I have to implement a service doing a lot of long running tasks and a bunch of file operations in the background. So my questions are:

- Is it generally a good idea to do that in any kind of service? What happens with an open file handle when the process gets killed?
- Is there a preferred way to achieve this like using a foreground service?

I think I won't be the first person having this type of problem/question, but I could not find anything on Google or SO. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Android services might get killed by the operating system at any possible time.

More accurately, Android app *processes* might get killed by the operating system at any point.

> There are no guaranteed lifecycle calls like onDestroy() you can rely on.

Correct. `onDestroy()` is very likely to be called, but it is not guaranteed.

> I have to implement a service doing a lot of long running tasks and a bunch of file operations in the background.

Pretty much any piece of software bigger than "hello, world" fits that description.

> Is it generally a good idea to do that in any kind of service?

You do not have much of an option. A service is what is helping to keep your process around when it no longer is in the foreground from a UI standpoint. If you do not use a service, your process lifetime will likely be on the order of minutes, maybe less. With a service, your process lifetime can be hours, though it depends a lot on the device (e.g., amount of system RAM) and user (e.g., how busy the user is and how many other apps want to do background work).

> What happens with an open file handle when the process gets killed?

If you have tried writing stuff to the file at about the point of process termination, any bytes not yet handed over to the OS (e.g., buffered in Java) will not be in the file.

> Is there a preferred way to achieve this

I have no idea what "this" is.

> like using a foreground service?

There are three main patterns for using a foreground service:

- Brief transactions. K9 Mail, for example, appears to use a foreground service while it is checking for new messages, but only during that short window.
- User-controlled operations. This is the conventional use case for foreground services. Music players, for example, will usually implement a foreground service for the music playback.
- "I am going to try to live forever" types of services. That's not especially practical, as foreground services do not live forever. Users also get irritated with foreground services where they do not understand what they are getting as trade-off for the system RAM/CPU consumption and the always-visible notification icon.

Whether any of these patterns fits your project is something you would need to determine for yourself.

Comment: what is your advice on designing file copy service?

Comment: @Vivek: I do not know what a file copy service is. In the nearly five years since I wrote this answer, foreground services have become much more important, as you cannot have a background service run for more than a minute. Alternatively, particularly if you can break the work into chunks, you could consider `WorkManager` from the Jetpack.